# Create variable that captures if there are missing fields in 4 string variables

Tags: r, string, for-loop, missing-data, dummy-variable

I am creating dummy variables where missing values are 1 and non-missing values are 0. The missing values are `NA`, i.e.:

```
NA
NA
Positive
NA
Negative
```

My code for one variable at a time successfully created the dummy variable:

```
library(dplyr)

#create new dummy variable
df <- mutate(df, newvar = ifelse(is.na(var1), 1,0))

#check
sum(df$newvar == 1)
```

I have 4 string variables and want to create a new dummy variable where missing values in any of the variables are 1, and non-missing values are 0. I tried reusing the above code:

```
mylist <- c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4")

for(i in mylist){
  df <- mutate(df, newvar = ifelse(is.na(i), 1,0))
}
```

I know that I am incorrectly using the `for` loop, but is this the correct approach, or should I be doing something different?

Comment: Please provide dummy data for the variable `df`. We can't tell what you mean by "missing values". Are these empty strings `""`, or `NA` or `NULL`? Also, are you using `mutate` from `dplyr`? If so, please make this explicit by using `dplyr::mutate(...)` or add this line to your code `library(dplyr)`. Otherwise, your code won't work for others.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the ask to reflect these comments. The missing values are ```NA```. Hope that clarifies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mutate` with `across`

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.0.0  
df <- df %>%
          mutate(across(all_of(mylist), ~ +(is.na(.)), .names = '{col}_newvar'))
```

if we have an earlier version, use `mutate_at`

```
df %>%
   mutate_at(vars(mylist), ~  +(is.na(.)))
```

---

If we need to create a new column that flags if there are any missing value in those columns in the 'mylist'

```
df1 <- df %>%
    mutate(newvar = +(rowSums(is.na(select(., all_of(mylist)))) > 0))
```

Comment: I think I must be misunderstanding something here because this is returning all zeroes when I ran it. Is ~ an operator? I tried searching for it but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @JSCarp Can you check the `packageVersion('dplyr')`   used version > 1.0.0

Comment: I checked and am running version 1.0.2. The specific error message I got is "Unknown or uninitialised column: `newvar`.[1] 0"

Comment: @JSCarp For me this is working with a reproducible example `data(iris); nm1 <- names(iris)[1:4]; head(iris) %>% mutate(across(all_of(nm1), ~ +(is.na(.))))`

Comment: Apologies, the first code you provided worked, it created a dummy variable for each of the 4 variables in my list. I was just confused because I want to create a single dummy variable that accounted for missing values in all of the variables in the list.

Comment: @JSCarp  Not clear.  Do you need if there is any missing value in those columns,n then flag 1 or else 0?

Comment: Yes, the new variable should flag 1 if there is a missing value in any of those columns, else 0.

Comment: Thank you, this works great, how would you accomplish the same thing but flag only if all the columns in 'mylist' had missing values? As opposed to if any of the columns had missing values.